# External loads on gold jewelry

Tags: metalworking, metal, jewelry

Assume that I'm going to investigate if jewelry pieces are strong enough under external loads. For example, consider a ring. I want to investigate if it can resist a punch force, or everyday forces like carrying a heavy suitcase while wearing the ring, or even sudden banging  to a wall accidentally.

Is there any guideline or standard or code that helps me determine the direction and magnitude of the external loads on the jewelry pieces? Any documentation on that? Sorry if it sounds like a stupid question, I'm just trying to find a hint.

I'm specifically focusing on the *gold* metal and alloys of it.

Comment: "Jewelry" is a term that encompasses such a wide range of materials that you won't find any scientific literature on the properties of it. But you certainly can find such information about specific materials like gold, silver, diamonds and others. One well-known example is that pure gold is so soft and malleable that it will bend when worn as a ring. So the gold used for jewelry is an alloy of gold and silver (and sometimes other metals) that is stronger and resists damage more.

Comment: @Elmy Thanks. I updated my post accordingly.

Comment: Have you ever had a gold ring break ? Do you know anyone who had a gold ring break ?

Comment: @blacksmith37 I have not. But there are people with broken gold jewelry like bracelets, necklaces, and more. The failure will be a concern especially if you, as the manufacturer, want to make the jewelry gold as light as possible :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an industry standard, [ASTM F2999-19](https://www.astm.org/f2999-19.html), but it's focus is determining safety (mechanical hazards and material toxicity).

---

[Here](https://technology.matthey.com/article/65/3/480-492/) you can find a study comparing the wear resistance between platinum and gold alloys. It uses "*standardised industrial procedures in order to provide comparable and reproducible conditions*".
I have linked all the standards used to official sites (which are not always particularly practical).

The following procedures are outlined in the paper:

- **Scratch testing**, using "*a conical [Rockwell C hardness tester](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rockwell_scale) with a diamond indenter under controlled loads*". Ground and polished 'coupons' were made of the 6 tested alloys (see [Figure 1](https://technology.matthey.com/documents/496120/615138/Frye-65-3-Jul21-f1.gif)), and these underwent "*scratching under both constant and increasing loads*".
  See paragraph '2.1 Scratch Test' for more details.
- **Wear testing**. Cubes were made of the alloys (see [Figure 2](https://technology.matthey.com/documents/496120/615138/Frye-65-3-Jul21-f2.gif)) for these tests.

  1. "*an **abrasion test** that utilises a stone and sand media*"
  2. "*a **corrosion test** in artificial human sweat*"
  3. "*a **polishing test** employing a nutshell media*"

  Tests 1 and 3 make use of an industrial standard for testing for the "*detection of nickel release*", [DIN EN 12472](https://www.en-standard.eu/din-en-12472-method-for-the-simulation-of-accelerated-wear-and-corrosion-for-the-detection-of-nickel-release-from-coated-items/) (see [Figure 3](https://technology.matthey.com/documents/496120/615138/Frye-65-3-Jul21-f3.gif)).
  See paragraph '2.2 Wear Testing' for more details.
  The corrosion test was performed according to the standard [ISO 3160-2](https://www.iso.org/standard/66162.html) for corrosion resistance, and "*involves application of artificial human sweat to the test cubes followed by heating in a closed chamber*".
  See paragraph '2.3 Corrosion Testing' for more details.
- "***Tensile testing** was performed in accordance with [ISO 6892-1](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:std:iso:6892:-1:ed-3:v1:en) and **microhardness testing** was done using a 100 g load (HV0.1) in accordance with [the withdrawn Vickers hardness test] [DIN EN ISO 6507-1](https://www.iso.org/standard/64065.html)*".
  More details on the mechanical properties testing that was performed can be found in [this PDF](https://www.techformcasting.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/Frye-Teresa-2017.pdf).

I realize these might not all be of import to you, but hopefully give you a starting point.

Comment: Uhm, shouldn't the content of the paper be properly marked as a quote? Or did you summarize the paper in your own words?

Comment: @Elmy The words outside the quotation marks are mine, and inside are quotes from the paper, yes.

Comment: Thanks :) It was great.

Comment: The link to the PDF file looks broken. Maybe [this](https://www.techformcasting.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/Frye-Teresa-2017.pdf) is the link. It is an awesome paper to read.

Comment: @Megidd Yes, that's it. I sillily linked to the file on my PC. Thanks!